# Algebraic (?) proof that Ricci form is closed

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $(M,\omega, J, g)$ be a Kähler manifold. The Ricci form of $M$ is defined as $\rho(X,Y)={\rm Ric}(JX,Y)$. I wanted to give a possibly coordinate-free proof that ${\rm d}\rho=0$. From the condition $\nabla J=0$ we have that $${\rm d}\rho(X,Y,Z) = (\nabla_X{\rm Ric})(JY,Z) +(\nabla_Y{\rm Ric})(JZ,X)+(\nabla_Z{\rm Ric})(JX,Y).$$I'm guessing that there is a smart way of using the second Bianchi identity to get the result from the above, but I can't see how to deal with terms of the form $\nabla_{JX}$. Also the fact that the second Bianchi identity is true for all connections makes me think that it might not be powerful enough. Help?

Comment: Just for my curiousity, what text are you reading ?

Comment: I'm actually takings bits here and there. Among the books I'm consulting are Moroianu's Lectures in Kähler Geometry, Ballmann's Lectures in Kähler Manifolds, Besse's Einstein Manifolds, and also Kobayashi & Nomizu volume 2.

Comment: Did you ever found such a proof?

Answer (score 2):

Andrei Moroianu gives such an algebraic proof in his "Lectures on Kähler Geometry" on p. 88.

First, he proves the formula
$$ 2\operatorname{Ric} (X,Y) = \operatorname{Tr}( R(X,JY) \circ J)
$$
using the first Bianchi identity.

Then, start computing $d \rho$ as done above, but the $J$s disappear, because $R$ preserves $J$, i.e. $R(JX, JY) = R(X, Y)$:
\begin{align*}
2d \rho &= 2(
(\nabla_X \operatorname{Ric})(JY, Z)+ 
(\nabla_Z \operatorname{Ric})(JX, Y)+
(\nabla_Y \operatorname{Ric})(JZ, X) )\\
&= \operatorname{Tr}((
(\nabla_X R)(Y, Z) +
(\nabla_Z R)(X, Y) +
(\nabla_Y R)(Z, X))\circ J)
=0
\end{align*}
where we finally could use the second Bianchi identity.